# How can I create a subfolder in each folder through Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, webp, gulp-4, gulpfile

Good day!

I want to automate the conversion of images to `webp` format. To avoid doing it manually or via online converters, I decided to use `gulp 4` and `gulp-webp`.

This is the structure of nesting folders in my project:

[image]

I want Gulp, when it finds a picture, so that it creates a folder called "webp" at the same nesting level and places the converted picture in this folder.

I want the following result:

[image]

My `Gulpfile.js`:

```js
let gulp = require('gulp'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp');

gulp.task('webp', () => {
    // './dev/img/**/*.{png,gif,jpg}' - all files in img and all files in subfolders in img


    return gulp.src('./dev/img/**/*.{png,gif,jpg}')
        .pipe(webp())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(gulp.src)) //something like this, but it doesn't work

    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the help of [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename).

To install gulp-rename run:

```sh
npm i -D gulp-rename
```

Then in your gulpfile.js add the import:

```js
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
```

Then change your stream like this:

```js
return gulp.src('./dev/img/**/*.{png,gif,jpg}')
    .pipe(webp())
    .pipe(rename({ prefix: 'webp/' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/img'));
```

The `prefix` option inserts "webp/" before the bare filename after the `dest` target "./dev/img".

Comment: This code in the img folder creates a webp folder and in it it already creates a hierarchy as in img (the only difference: files in webp format).
But I need a webp folder to be created with each image at the same nesting level, and this image converted into webp should be placed in this folder.
I wrote in the description of the question what result is needed (second picture).

Comment: @Konstantin Ah okay, I misunderstood that part. I've updated my answer now.

Comment: No need for the `, { base: './dev/img' }` parameter since that is what `base` would be set to automatically anyway.